# Объявление структуры после функции в которой она использована

Tags: структуры, c++, visual-c++

```
void func(){
    str s;
};
struct str{
int i;
};
```

Компилятор пишет, что `struct` не определен. Как исправить? Функцию и стурктуру местами менять нельзя.

Comment: вначале было с, потом vc++. Может автор вопроса определиться, а то хотя некоторые и верят, что с и с++ - это почти одно и тоже, но по факту, это два немножко разных языка с похожим синтаксисом.

Answer (score 2):

Если это был бы с++, то задача действительно простая. Но автор поставил тег С. В этом случае просто так написать

```
void func()
 {
   str s;
 }
```

нельзя. Не скомпилируется. Нужно хотя бы так

```
void func()
{
    struct str s;
}
```

В си предопределение структуры похоже не поможет. Для этого нужно объявлять как указатель.

```
struct str;

void func(){
    struct str *s;
};
struct str{
int i;
};
```

Comment: Да, кстати, неоднократно сталкивался что просто писать `str s` в чистом Си недостаточно, а нужно `struct str s`. Это что за фича такая? Когда появилась? И почему современным компилятором вроде как это по барабану?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в Си структуры и переменные находятся в разных пространствах имен. И чтобы объявить структуру нужно взять ее из того пространства имен, в котором она определена. Возможно современные компиляторы такое ограничение просто выкинули, ведь C++ как-то обходится ведь без этого.

Comment: да не по барабану. Плюсовые не требуют, а сишные - требуют. Такой синтаксис. Но другое дело, что в си есть хитрый прием

    typedef struct str{
      int i;
    } str;

и после этого можно использовать просто `str`.

Comment: Это какое-то скотство получается =) В принципе, логика есть. Указатель всегда имеет определенный размер, а структура может иметь произвольный размер, так что компилятор заранее не знает сколько нужно выделить памяти. Хотя это кажется какими-то искусственными ограничениями.

Answer (score 0):

Дурацкая задача. Можно сделать предварительное определение.

```
 struct str; // вся магия здесь, по крайней мере с классами это работает 8-)

 void func()
 {
   str s;
 }

 struct str
 {
   int i;
 };
```

Comment: ага, в си и классы.

Comment: @gecube, пишет error C2079: "s" использует неопределенный struct "str"

Comment: предварительное определение будет работать если в функции будет тока указатель или ссылка на эту структуру и не будет использоваться.Предварительное определение используют в основном в заголовках когда надо в к примеру в классе использовать указатель на структуру или в определение функции как параметр передавать структуру по указателю и ненужно было подключать заголовочные файлы.